# Salesforce Einstein Chatbot Close Action

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-einstein

I have implemented the Einstein Chatbot onto my salesforce sandbox. I want to know how to add an action after clicking the close button.

Presently, when *clicking [x] on chat -> Confirm End Chat -> Close Chat*.

I want to make it so that this flow is implemented:
*clicking [x] on chat -> custom action -> Close chat*

Any suggestion?

Regards,
Shylesh